# package and distribute JavaScript library such that it can be imported as a script or as a npm module

Tags: javascript, npm

I am amateur in using JavaScript, and trying to develop a utility which is dependent on a JS SDK. I want to use npm and create this utility code such that I create a new npm module - so that others can use in there npm project and frameworks like react, angular etc

and I also want to package it and minify with its dependent SDK - so that developer can use the same library using a script tag as well.

So please guide me or refer me some resources online which can explain me this 2 things in a clean manner.

Comment: You just described what you want, so a simple Google search will *immediately* help you. [First result](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-node-js-modules)

Comment: 1) Break your problem down into subproblems, 2) research each problem. 3) if you get stuck with any of them, you can ask specific questions on stackoverflow (clearly stating where you got stuck.) Your question basically asks someone to write a tutorial, which is not really appropriate for SO.

Comment: I already tried doing that @Evert, I wasn't sure which is the best practice followed by experts and as I said i am amateur - so I am looking at some expert guidance

Comment: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/anatomy-of-js-module-systems-and-building-libraries-fadcd8dbd0e - seems to be a good read I guess